# IOS check on app if GPS is off

Tags: ios, gps, mkmapview

Hi I have an app that gives you locations on the mapview, is there any method to implement on an IF.

I would like my app to check if you don't have the gps active instead of showing you the map it will show you an image saying you don't have connection.

I would like to do something similar if you don't have signal as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can check whether the user denied the location services for you application by

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied
```

Otherwise you can also check whether location services are available at a system level by

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]
```

So the check you may want to perform in your app looks like

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && 
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    // show the map
} else {
    // show error
}
```

Comment: The presence of kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted should also be accounted for now.

Comment: This answer is wrong. That doesn't tell you if you're in an area where GPS is unavailable and are relying on crowdsourced location data from nearby bssid.